# Replace specific text with a redacted version using Python

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, lstm

I am looking to do the opposite of what has been done here:

```
import re

text = '1234-5678-9101-1213 1415-1617-1819-hello'

re.sub(r"(\d{4}-){3}(?=\d{4})", "XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-", text)

output = 'XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-1213 1415-1617-1819-hello'
```

*[Partial replacement with re.sub()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16327590/partial-replacement-with-re-sub)*

My overall goal is to replace all `XXXX` within a text using a neural network. `XXXX` can represent names, places, numbers, dates, etc. that are in a .csv file.

The end result would look like:

```
XXXX went to XXXX XXXXXX
```

Sponge Bob went to Disney World.

In short, I am unmasking text and replacing it with a generated dataset using fuzzy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using [named-entity recognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition) (NER). It's fairly simple and there are out-of-the-shelf tools out there to do it, such as [spaCy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaCy).

NER is an [NLP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) task where a neural network (or other method) is trained to detect certain entities, such as names, places, dates and organizations.

Example:

> Sponge Bob went to South beach, he payed a ticket of $200! 
>   I know, Michael is a good person, he goes to McDonalds, but donates to charity at St. Louis street.

Returns:

[image: NER with spacy]

Just be aware that this is not 100%!

Here are a little snippet for you to try out:

```
import spacy

phrases = ['Sponge Bob went to South beach, he payed a ticket of $200!', 'I know, Michael is a good person, he goes to McDonalds, but donates to charity at St. Louis street.']
nlp = spacy.load('en')
for phrase in phrases:
   doc = nlp(phrase)
   replaced = ""
   for token in doc:
      if token in doc.ents:
         replaced+="XXXX "
      else:
         replaced+=token.text+" "
```

Read more here: https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#named-entities

You could, instead of replacing with XXXX, replace based on the entity type, like:

```
if ent.label_ == "PERSON":
   replaced += "<PERSON> "
```

Then:

```
import re, random

personames = ["Jack", "Mike", "Bob", "Dylan"]

phrase = re.replace("<PERSON>", random.choice(personames), phrase)
```

Comment: Thank you. I will test this out over the weekend. This helps out a lot and points in the right direction.